# Reference recommendation: Mackey Topological in terms of Compactness and Completeness and Dunford-Pettis on Topological groups

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, reference-request, topological-groups

Unfortunately, I have to work with Mackey Topology on a topological group under the duality theory. My primary reference is [Topological Vector Space](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387987262), but it is concise. I have searched for literature; it is scattered and seems not so much. I am interested in completeness, compactness, and, most importantly, Dunford-Pettis properties. Any help is needed.

Answer (score 1):

*Köthe*'s Toplogical Vector Spaces I is a pretty good book, where $\S21$ seems to cover the Mackey topology fairly well.  It is a little old though and I doubt it covers anything on Dunford-Pettis.

*Bogachev* is another good author for these kinds of things, so you could try Topological Vector Spaces and Their Applications by him and *Smolyanov* though you might find some of the results you are interested in relegated to the exercises.

I don't have it to hand to check, but I also seem to recall *Treves*'s Topological Vector Spaces being comprehensive, so assuming you're checking all these in a library, that might also be worth a look.

Comment: Thanks, I will check them first!

Comment: Find the last two! Now I have something to do for the holiday! Cheers!